# How do i check if my sqlite column is not in my dataframe?

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I have a sqlite database with `10000 rows`, `6 columns`, and 1 unique column called `Code`. I also have a `pandas df` which has `6 columns`, a unique column called `Code` but with `9000 rows`.

How do I check which are the `1000` rows that are from the `sql database` that is **not in** the `df`?

I tried:

```
d = connection.execute('SELECT DISTINCT "Code" FROM "my_table"').fetchall()
for each_row_sql, each_row_df in zip(d, df['Code']):
   if each_row_sql[0] not in each_row_df:
        print(each_row_sql[0])  # just to see which are the rows that are not in the sql database
```

But this doesn't work. It just returns me everything

Comment: you can use EXISTS as a boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small demo:

let's first generate a sample DF (10 rows, 3 columns) and write it to SQLiteDB file:

```
In [40]: import sqlite3
    ...: from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    ...:
    ...: engine = create_engine('sqlite:///d:/temp/sqlalchemy_example.db')
    ...:
    ...: x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (10,3)), columns=list("abc"))
    ...: x.insert(0, 'Code', np.arange(len(x)))
    ...: x.to_sql('my_table', engine, index=False)
    ...:

In [41]: x
Out[41]:
   Code  a  b  c
0     0  4  6  6
1     1  2  5  8
2     2  3  9  2
3     3  3  1  2
4     4  9  8  4
5     5  2  8  1
6     6  5  1  8
7     7  8  9  7
8     8  0  7  3
9     9  2  6  3
```

Now let's generate our `df` with 5 rows, 3 columns:

```
In [42]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (5,3)), columns=list("abc"))
    ...: df.insert(0, 'Code', np.arange(len(df)))
    ...:

In [43]: df
Out[43]:
   Code  a  b  c
0     0  8  4  8
1     1  1  1  0
2     2  5  5  2
3     3  2  2  8
4     4  3  2  2
```

Note both data sets have **unique** `Code` column.

**Solution:**

```
In [44]: db_df = pd.read_sql('select * from my_table', engine)
    ...: missing = db_df.loc[~db_df.Code.isin(df.Code)]
    ...: print(missing)
    ...:
   Code  a  b  c
5     5  2  8  1
6     6  5  1  8
7     7  8  9  7
8     8  0  7  3
9     9  2  6  3
```

**UPDATE:**

`~` is a negation of boolean index:

```
In [45]: db_df.Code.isin(df.Code)
Out[45]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: Code, dtype: bool

In [46]: ~db_df.Code.isin(df.Code)
Out[46]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
Name: Code, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxU, was wondering, what does `~` mean ? Also, is it possible to structure `missing` to be a `boolean` response? so that I can do, `if missing: # do code`?

Comment: @jakewong, please check UPDATE